# Grafana status board

Tags: json, grafana

Not sure if this is possible but we're trying to create an overall status dashboard in grafana using the singlestat panel. We used templating to group our hosts into two sites and using the packet loss value from hostalive in Icinga2. We'd like the singlestat panel to show the percentage of hosts down but sometimes we get null values. Here's the JSON from our panels:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "title": "Host Group 2",
  "span": 6,
  "type": "singlestat",
  "targets": [
    {
      "target": "icinga2.$group1.host.hostalive.perfdata.pl.value",
      "refId": "A",
      "hide": true
    },
    {
      "target": "keepLastValue(averageSeries(#A))",
      "refId": "B",
      "textEditor": true,
      "targetFull": "keepLastValue(averageSeries(icinga2.$group1.host.hostalive.perfdata.pl.value), 10000)"
    }
  ],
  "links": [],
  "datasource": null,
  "maxDataPoints": "",
  "interval": null,
  "cacheTimeout": null,
  "format": "percent",
  "prefix": "",
  "postfix": "",
  "nullText": null,
  "valueMaps": [
    {
      "value": "null",
      "op": "=",
      "text": "N/A"
    }
  ],
  "mappingTypes": [
    {
      "name": "value to text",
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "range to text",
      "value": 2
    }
  ],
  "rangeMaps": [
    {
      "from": "null",
      "to": "null",
      "text": "N/A"
    }
  ],
  "mappingType": 1,
  "nullPointMode": "connected",
  "valueName": "current",
  "prefixFontSize": "50%",
  "valueFontSize": "80%",
  "postfixFontSize": "50%",
  "thresholds": "50, 100",
  "colorBackground": true,
  "colorValue": false,
  "colors": [
    "rgba(50, 172, 45, 0.97)",
    "rgba(237, 129, 40, 0.89)",
    "rgba(245, 54, 54, 0.9)"
  ],
  "sparkline": {
    "show": false,
    "full": false,
    "lineColor": "rgb(31, 120, 193)",
    "fillColor": "rgba(31, 118, 189, 0.18)"
  },
  "gauge": {
    "show": false,
    "minValue": 0,
    "maxValue": 100,
    "thresholdMarkers": true,
    "thresholdLabels": false
  }
}
```

The polling interval for the hosts is every ten minutes, the grafana board range is "today" and set to refresh every second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out with the keeplastvalue.

```
"targets": [
    {
      "hide": true,
      "refId": "A",
      "target": "exclude(keepLastValue(icinga2.$group1.host.hostalive.perfdata.pl.value, 144), '1-99')",
      "textEditor": true
    },
    {
      "refId": "B",
      "target": "averageSeries(#A)",
      "targetFull": "averageSeries(icinga2.$group1.host.hostalive.perfdata.pl.value)",
      "textEditor": false
    }
  ],
```